# Standards for when to use custom operators

Tags: f#, standards, custom-operator

I'm currently reading Real-World Functional Programming, and it briefly mentions in-fix operators as being one of the main benefits of custom operators.  Are there any sort of standards for when to use or not use custom operators in F#?  I'm looking for answers equivalent to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

For reference, here is the quote to which @JohnPalmer is referring from [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf):

> 3.8 Operator Definitions 
>
> Avoid defining custom symbolic operators in F#-facing library designs.
>
> Custom operators are essential in some
> situations and are highly useful notational devices within a large
> body of implementation code. For new users of a library, named
> functions are often easier to use.  In addition custom symbolic
> operators can be hard to document, and users find it more difficult to
> lookup help on operators, due to existing limitations in IDE and
> search engines.
>
> As a result, it is generally best to publish your
> functionality as named functions and members.

Comment: Why is this question not constructive?  Knowing community standards on when to use/not use language features is important for writing readable code.  And from the faq on what is a good question to ask: "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession"

Comment: According to microsoft, the answer is almost never: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf

Comment: @JohnPalmer Good find.  It specifically says to not use them in F# facing _library_ design.  I've updated my question with a bit more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom infix operators are a nice feature in *some* situations, but when you use them, you have to be very careful to keep your code readable - so the recommendation from F# design guidelines applies *most* of the time. If I was writing Real-World Functional Programming again, I would be a bit less enthusiastic about them, because they really should be used carefuly :-).

That said, there are some F# libraries that make good use of custom operators and sometimes they work quite nicely. I think [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) (parser combinator library) is one case - though maybe they have too many of them. Another example is a [XML DSL](http://fssnip.net/9x) which uses `@=`.

In general, when you're writing *ordinary* F# library, you probably do not want to expose them. However, when you're writing a *domain specific language*, custom operators might be useful.

Comment: DSL do seem the area where they would cause the least amount of confusion.  Thanks for the input!